# Android FragmentManager lifecycle

Tags: android, fragmentmanager

I am a beginner of Android development. I have a question when FragmentManager is detroyed? I have called the method: "registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(FragmentLifecycleCallbacks cb, boolean recursive)" on activity onCreate, I find the official comment of "All registered callbacks will be automatically unregistered when this FragmentManager is destroyed". but when the FragmentManager destroyed？ 
Thank you in advance!

[FragmentManager#registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks,%20boolean))

and All registered callbacks will be automatically unregistered when this FragmentManager is destroyed. but unregisterFragmentLifecycleCallbacks is NOT called.
[FragmentManager#unregisterFragmentLifecycleCallbacks()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#unregisterFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks))

Answer (score 1):

The fragment manager manages fragments and so when the instance of which it is called i.e. in your case is the activity, will be destroyed only when that existing activity is destroyed.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!